# How do I find what a percent-defined macro in a Visual Studio project means?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am looking at a project in which the Delay Loaded DLLs setting on the Linker Input property page is "%(DelayLoadedDLLs)".  How do I find what the expansion of that macro is so that I can see exactly what DLLs are being delay-loaded?

Comment: One very effective way to get this kind of data is to turn on the binary log creation and opening the build log with the binary log viewer for msbuild. https://msbuildlog.com/

Comment: You probably misspelled DelayLoadDLLs.  It is a standard build property that can be set by a project property sheet, currently used only when building a project that targets the static MFC libraries.  It delay-loads oleacc.dll for histerical reasons.  See the macro expansion by selecting the property, clicking the down-arrow in the textbox and selecting Edit.  Inherited value will typically be empty, the Macros button shows values.